# Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio invalid in the select list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlsrv

I was trying to search from my table and use group by but I was receiving error while executing the query. below is my query and the error I am getting:

```
select * from loans where ac_no='100001' group by ac_no, branch
```

and the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Column 'loans.gl_no' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please, what am I doing wrong

Comment: what are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: You cannot use SELECT * when you are using a GROUP BY. You have to specify what happens to any columns not listed in the GROUP BY clause (i.e. MIN(), MAX() or some other aggregate, since there will be many possible values for the one row output by GROUP BY)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to aggregate something...

```
select ac_no, branch, count(*)
from loans
where ac_no = '100001'
group by 
   ac_no
 , branch
```

If you are just trying to select rows, you do not need `group by`

```
select *
from loans
where ac_no = '100001'
```

If you are trying to select distinct rows...

```
select distinct *
from loans
where ac_no = '100001'
```

Comment: I'm trying to return a minimum values returned from the database in case a user appears multiple times.

Comment: @fagbemiayodele For that instance, would you maybe want the first or last record based on some `date` column instead of `min()` values? In which case I would recommend `select top 1 * from ... where ... order by createddate desc`.